# Test upstart script without reboot

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, testing

Is there a way test an upstart script without rebooting the system ?

I am working on a system that I really don't want to reboot - yet I want to be reasonably sure that my newly written upstart script will work properly once I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to run the start command you can do:

```
service <service name> start
```

and then

```
service <service name> stop
```

This will actually run your script to start the service.. if you want to test it without potentially messing up the server.. you may wan to try it somewhere else or change it so that it does not actually execute anything but instead logs the command it would have executed.. before you do this I would at least run the bash -n command on it to make sure it does not have syntax issues.